# Mono on Linux Ubuntu - Some Unicode characters will not display at the end of a string using DrawString()

Tags: mono

I'm making a cross-platform .NET Framework 4.8 app where the same EXE needs to run on Windows and run on Linux using Mono.  The app allows the language to be toggled dynamically between English and Japanese using font "MS Gothic.ttc".  The app has always worked fine on Windows, but on Linux (Ubuntu now but Yocto ultimately) after installing the "MS Gothic.ttc" font on Ubuntu, it will not draw certain Japanese characters (i.e. 0x8A08) if that character is at the end of a string.  If the character is in the middle of the string, DrawString() draws all the characters (i.e. 0x91CD 0x91CF 0x8A08 only draws the first 2 characters, but 0x91CD 0x8A08 0x91CF draws all 3 characters).

Also, what are the current thoughts about how long Mono on Linux will be supported on Ubuntu and Yocto?  At some point, I’d like to use .NET Maui on Linux, but Microsoft hasn’t done that yet.  Plus, porting my .NET Framework WinForms UI to .NET Maui on Linux will probably take a lot of time.

I have tried reversing the characters and then the DrawString() works correctly.

Comment: Thoughts? https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/ and https://halfblood.pro/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea You already wasted a lot of time on a dead end (libgdiplus and Mono WinForms), and if you started porting you should have done a lot more now.